# Why does my car stutter and sometimes die at low RPMs, but only when the fuel tank is full?

Tags: engine, chevrolet, fuel-system, stall, malibu

My 2005 Chevy Malibu has a very strange problem, it sometimes dies at low RPMs, but only when the fuel tank is full. The problem goes away when the tank drops to a little bit above the 3/4 mark. I've never had this problem until the fuel pump was replaced. Any advice would be much appreciated. My Malibu has the LS trim with a 3.5L V6 engine. The fuel pump was replaced around February.

Comment: which engine does the Malibu have?  how long ago was the fuel pump replaced?

Comment: I added the information to my question.